# File Size become large after extract from zip file

Tags: c#, winforms, zip, extract, filesize

This is a weird situation i'm facing right now. so i have a program which extract zip files. inside the zip files there are some image files. after extracting the files. One or two of the image's file size  become very big.

the original file size is around 200 Kb. after extracting it can go like 2 Mb.

it not always happen but sometimes. can anyone help me with this ?

this is the code i use to extract the files:

```
  fileName = Path.GetFileName(fi[i].FullName);
  folderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi[i].FullName);

  ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(SourceFolder + "\\" + fileName, ExtractFolder + "\\" + folderName);
```

OK i'm new to stackoverflow and i don't know how to edit question and make new topic the correct way

it turn out not the extracted files that become big. so what my program does is view the extracted image and rotate it then save the orientation by replacing the original image with the new rotated image.

is there any way to rotate and save the orientation without replacing the original file? so the file size will be the same

or how to compress the file size to around 200-300 Kb

Comment: What makes you think that they *shouldn't* be that size after uncompressing?

Comment: You are really asking why files get bigger when you decompress them?!

Comment: @MatthewWatson because the original size is not that big? and it happened to some file. not all file in that zip file

Comment: @DavidG yes, why some of the files get bigger after i decompress them

Comment: To clarify, the original file before being zipping was 200Kb. It was then zipped up with other files. After you extracted that file from the zip file, the original is now up to something like 2MB size, but you where expecting it to be unzipped back to 200Kb again to match the original size. Is that correct?

Comment: And if you view the ZIP file in Windows Explorer, how big does it think the contained file should be?

Comment: hi @kevchadders. i wasn't expecting to be the exact size. but not huge different either. i was expecting to be around the original size. do you know why?

Comment: @MatthewWatson when i view the ZIP file in Windows Explorer. the file size still the same as the original file.

Comment: Have you tried to open the 2MB file in a Image program? Does it open? Can you open using a text editor and check if its a mix of multiple files?